# How to mark search term in php

Tags: php

How to mark search term in php

below code replace the lower case to upper care and vice versa
like if search term is samsung then result is samsung Galaxy S4 or if 
search term is AP the result is Apple. 
please help,

`$high = $searchTerm;`
`$repl = '<span class="hilite">' . $high . '</span>';`
`$out = preg_replace('/('.$high.')/i', $repl , $adtitle);`

i am echoing $out

Comment: do you mean an autosuggest in textbox ?

Comment: no, i have search engine in my webpage. i am using LIKE query @AndreiAndrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will highlight your term while preserving the original case.

```
$high = preg_quote($searchTerm);
$out = preg_replace("~$high~i", '<span class="hilite">\0</span>', $adtitle);
```

Or, if you want to respect word boundaries:

```
$high = preg_quote($searchTerm);
$out = preg_replace("/\b$high\b/i", '<span class="hilite">\0</span>', $adtitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to show results regardless of its case.

If that's it, try changing your query to `LOWER(column) LIKE LOWER(term)` so that they're returned from the database in first place.